# how laravel extends class without including them

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I encountered the topic called 'namespace' in php after I started working with Laravel.  While trying to understand namespace I found that to extend a class under a namespace, I need to include that class in my current page.  Like the following:

**directory '..\teacher\Teacher.php'**

```
    namespace Teacher;

    class Teacher{
       public $headTeacher='mr X';

   }
```

to extend the calss i need to **include** that page as well as **use** the namespace

**directory '..\studnet\student.php'**

```
use \Teacher\Teacher;  //use the namespace


include('../teacher/Teacher.php'); // include the page

   class mathTeacher extends Teacher{

    public function headTeacherName(){
       echo $this->headTeacher;
    }

   }

  $student=new mathTeacher();
  $student->headTeacherName();
```

***I am wondering how Laravel only use namespace to include classes.  Like if I create a controller called 'userController'.  The structure of the page is***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;  

class userController extends Controller{

}
```

They never included the php page which holds the ***'controller'*** class.  But they were able to extend it somehow.  Also I can use `"View" ,"Auth"` just by using the `use View` or `use Auth` command.  How is it done? How can I implement the same with the code I have provided?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most frameworks use autoloader.

Comment: There is a big process behind of each request. When you access for example index.php laravel load all the necessary classes to let people like you and me using them without including them manually. If you want to understand a little bit this behavior make your first "hello world" project using a tool named "composer"

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses composer.php for autoloading the classes. All classes in the autoload directory will be pre loaded. So you can just use the namespace and consume anywhere across the application.

[Learn more about composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/), composer config can be found on composer.json in your root path for the application